# Unable to write to root from regular user

Tags: rhel, write

I'm doing some exercises from a RHEL 8 book and I need to write to root from a regular user. I'm using RHEL VMs with VirtualBox and Windows 10 as host. I'm logged in as root, and I have two terminals open. On the second terminal, from root I switched to a regular user using

```
su user1
```

However when I tried writing to root using

```
write root
```

I got

```
write: root has messages disabled
```

I then did

```
who
```

to verify who was logged in and I got

```
root    :0        2022-08-31 16:00 (:0)
```

Then using `whoami`, I got `user1`
On the other terminal where root was logged in, I did

```
mesg
```

and I got `is y`

Why am I unable to write to root?

Comment: did you read the error message?

Comment: Yes, and I checked that using ```mesg``` and the response was ```is y``` meaning root allows writing.

Comment: How do I enable messages to root?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I simply needed to logon to my VM as both users (root and regular user) using SSH. In my case I used PuTTY, and once I logged in both as root and as the regular user, I was able to send messages.